# Webpack outputting ES6 code despite ES2015 preset

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing client-side react code with ES6 synthax and have been using webpack to transform into ES5 using Babel, and generate a bundle that I send to browser.

It works great on Chrome. However, I recently tried my bundle on Safari 9.x and it failed with :
`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`
Upon closer inspection I noticed this code in the bundle.js was causing the error:

```
// customized for this use-case
const isObject = x =>
    typeof x === 'object' &&
    x !== null &&
    !(x instanceof RegExp) &&
    !(x instanceof Error) &&
    !(x instanceof Date);
```

I thought webpack was supposed to eliminate ES6 code (since I'm using the `es2015` preset) so I'm surprised that a `const` and an arrow function were still in the bundle. **Why is there ES6 code still in my bundle? Is there any way for me to get webpack to transform that into ES5?**

Here's a snippet of my webpack.config.js that I thought would have done the job of removing this synthax but didn't:

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    include: APP_DIR,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] //, 'react-hmre']
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your test has '?' instead of '$'. Maybe try this test: test: /\.jsx$/,

Comment: Try test: /\.jsx?$/,

Comment: @Imran I don't think this is a function I wrote, it must be either a library or webpack. @Niels I have `?` to allow both .js and .jsx files to be processed by webpack

Comment: I just did `/\.jsx?$/` and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: What file is that code in? Your code only compiles things in `APP_DIR`, is the file in that folder? How are you calculating `APP_DIR`?

Comment: the code I showed is in the bundle outputted from webpack. For `APP_DIR`  I do `var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js');` this seems to work fine since the bundle does all it's supposed to do. The only problem is the presence ES6 code in the bundle.

Comment: I've tracked down the problem to a node module I'm using: [snakecase-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snakecase-keys). When I remove the imports of this module, the problem disappears. I guess Babel loader doesn't run on imported node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

After much head scratching and investigation it turned out that one node module, snakecase-keys, is built using ES6 synthax. Since my webpack is only targeting my static directory and not my node modules it did not get Babel'd

This fixed it:

```
module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        // exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: [APP_DIR, /node_modules\/snakecase-keys/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] //, 'react-hmre']
        }
      }]
}
```